# input fields overlapping in layout

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to create a form with text field, age, country and gender. however there seems to be a problem. The age and gender field seems to be overlapping on each other. How do I make every  input field be in it's own row instead of overlapping

[codesandbox, the problem seems to be there only when you open the website in full](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-goldstine-wmofr?file=/src/App.js:0-2692)

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";

import { Container, Row, Col, Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import {
  CountryDropdown,
  RegionDropdown,
  CountryRegionData
} from "react-country-region-selector";

const App = () => {
  const [age, setAge] = useState("");
  const [gender, setGender] = useState("");
  const [country, setCountry] = useState("");
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    console.log(age, gender, country, text);
  };
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Container>
        <Row md={4}>
          <Col xs={12} md={7}>
            <Form.Group controlId="textarea">
              <Form.Label />
              <Form.Control
                as="textarea"
                rows="20"
                onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)}
                placeholder="Enter you text"
              />
            </Form.Group>
          </Col>
          <Col xs={12} md={5}>
            <Form className="mb-3">
              <Form.Row>
                <Form.Group as={Row}>
                  <Form.Label>
                    Age
                    <Form.Control
                      type="text"
                      name="age"
                      value={age}
                      onChange={e => setAge(e.target.value)}
                      required
                    />
                  </Form.Label>
                </Form.Group>

                <br />
                <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.SelectCustomSizeSm" as={Row}>
                  <Form.Label>Gender</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control
                    as="select"
                    size="sm"
                    custom
                    value={gender}
                    onChange={e => setGender(e.target.value)}
                  >
                    <option>Male</option>
                    <option>Female</option>
                    <option>Prefer Not To Say</option>
                  </Form.Control>
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group>
                  <Form.Label>
                    Country
                    <CountryDropdown
                      value={country}
                      onChange={e => setCountry(e)}
                    />
                  </Form.Label>
                </Form.Group>
              </Form.Row>
            </Form>
            <Form.Group as={Col}>
              <input
                type="submit"
                className="btn btn-dark my-1"
                value="Submit"
                onClick={handleSubmit}
              />
            </Form.Group>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first remove the as={Row} attributes from both the Age and Gender form group as its not the use case for what you are trying to achieve. The <Form.Label> of the age form group component is not used properly.

After making those changes it worked fine. Here is a snippet

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";

import { Container, Row, Col, Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import {
  CountryDropdown,
  RegionDropdown,
  CountryRegionData
} from "react-country-region-selector";

const App = () => {
  const [age, setAge] = useState("");
  const [gender, setGender] = useState("");
  const [country, setCountry] = useState("");
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    console.log(age, gender, country, text);
  };
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Container>
        <Row md={4}>
          <Col xs={12} md={7}>
            <Form.Group controlId="textarea">
              <Form.Label />
              <Form.Control
                as="textarea"
                rows="20"
                onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)}
                placeholder="Enter you text"
              />
            </Form.Group>
          </Col>
          <Col xs={12} md={5}>
            <Form className="mb-3">
              <Form.Row>
                <Form.Group>
                  <Form.Label>
                    Age
                  </Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                      type="text"
                      name="age"
                      value={age}
                      onChange={e => setAge(e.target.value)}
                      required
                    />
                </Form.Group>

                <br />
                <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.SelectCustomSizeSm">
                  <Form.Label>Gender</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control
                    as="select"
                    size="sm"
                    custom
                    value={gender}
                    onChange={e => setGender(e.target.value)}
                  >
                    <option>Male</option>
                    <option>Female</option>
                    <option>Prefer Not To Say</option>
                  </Form.Control>
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group>
                  <Form.Label>
                    Country
                    <CountryDropdown
                      value={country}
                      onChange={e => setCountry(e)}
                    />
                  </Form.Label>
                </Form.Group>
              </Form.Row>
            </Form>
            <Form.Group as={Col}>
              <input
                type="submit"
                className="btn btn-dark my-1"
                value="Submit"
                onClick={handleSubmit}
              />
            </Form.Group>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to remove `as={Row}` from `<Form.Group as={Row}>`.

```
<Container>
  <Row md={4}>
    <Col xs={12} md={7}>
      {/* ... */}
    </Col>
    <Col xs={12} md={5}>
      <Form className="mb-3">
        <Form.Row>
          {/* <Form.Group as={Row}> */}
          <Form.Group>
            <Form.Label>
              Age
              <Form.Control type="text" name="age" required />
            </Form.Label>
          </Form.Group>

          <br />

          {/* <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.SelectCustomSizeSm" as={Row}> */}
          <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.SelectCustomSizeSm">
            <Form.Label>Gender</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control as="select" size="sm" custom>
              <option>Male</option>
              <option>Female</option>
              <option>Prefer Not To Say</option>
            </Form.Control>
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group>{/* ... */}</Form.Group>
        </Form.Row>
      </Form>
      <Form.Group as={Col}>{/* ... */}</Form.Group>
    </Col>
  </Row>
</Container>
```

Alternatively, you can remove `<Form.Row />` entirely. The solution you choose depends on the layout you expect.